# How to swap and migrate index field value in different documents by Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Say I have an Elasticsearch index Employee with **field emp_id** and I mistakenly saved the documents with **emp_id=1** instead of **emp_id=2** and **emp_id=2** instead of **emp_id=1**.

**Sample documents on index Employee**

```
[
    {
        "emp_id": "1",
        "name": "aaaa"
    },
    {
        "emp_id": "2",
        "name": "bbbb"
    },
    {
        "emp_id": "3",
        "name": "cccc"
    },
    {
        "emp_id": "4",
        "name": "dddd"
    }
]
```

Now I want to change/update all the document's emp_id value from **emp_id=1** to **emp_id=2** and also change **emp_id=2** to **emp_id=1** using an Elasticsearch query.

So the above documents should be changed/updated like this:

```
[
    {
        "emp_id": "2",
        "name": "aaaa"
    },
    {
        "emp_id": "1",
        "name": "bbbb"
    },
    {
        "emp_id": "3",
        "name": "cccc"
    },
    {
        "emp_id": "4",
        "name": "dddd"
    }
]
```

**Note:**
emp_id = 1,2,3,4 are all present in the same index. I just want to swap and migrate the emp_id 1 and 2's values without affecting other documents in index.

How to do this in Elasticsearch in a atomic fashion?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an ingest pipeline and the [`_update_by_query` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html):

First create an ingest pipeline with a [script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html) that will do the atomic change

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/swap_ids
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
        ctx.id = (ctx.id == '1') ? '2' : '1';
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, select all documents to be updated (i.e. the ones with `id = 1 or 2`) and update them all using the pipeline you just created:

```
POST test/_update_by_query?pipeline=swap_ids
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "id": ["1", "2"]
    }
  }
}
```

That's it!